# How do I break an outer loop from an inner one in Perl?

Tags: loops, perl, break, control-flow

Suppose I have a piece of Perl code like:

```
foreach my $x (@x) {
 foreach my $y (@z) {
  foreach my $z (@z) {
   if (something()) {
    # I want to break free!
   }
   # do stuff 
  }
  # do stuff
 }
 # do stuff
}
```

If `something()` is true, I would like to break ('last') all the loops.

how can I do that?
I thought of two options, both of which I don't like: 
Using something `GOTO`
Adding a boolean variable which will mark `something()` is true, check this var in each of the loops before they resume and `last()` if it's true.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: In Perl, the comment token is spelled `#`, not `//`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use a label:

```
OUTER:
foreach my $x (@x) {
 foreach my $y (@z) {
  foreach my $z (@z) {
   if (something()) {
    last OUTER;
   }
   # do stuff 
  }
  # do stuff
 }
 # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The "last LABEL" syntax is described [in the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html).

Answer (score -1):

Note that you can also do this in a one liner. Use the keyword LINE. e.g. `perl -ane 'next if length$F[5]!=1; for(split/,/,$F[6]){next LINE if length$_!=1}; print'`